# Studying the sign of this function without the derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, continuity

- I want to study where $f(x) > 0$ and where $f(x) < 0$.

Is there a way we can study the sign of

$$f(x) = \frac{2 x^3-x^2+5 x+4}{-2 x^3-6 x^2+8 x}$$

withouth making use of the derivative? I mean studying $f(x) > 0$ won't be easy since cubic equations are involved.
Yet I know the domain is
$$D: x\in(-\infty, -4)\cup(-4, 0) \cup (0, 1)\cup (1, +\infty)$$

I've managed to compute the limits:

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = -1$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{\pm}} f(x) = \pm \infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to -4^{\pm}} f(x) = \pm \infty $$

$$\lim_{x\to 1^{\pm}} f(x) = \mp \infty$$

I know also that $f(x)$ is continuous on its domain.

Now, since $\lim_{x\to -4^+} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x) = -\infty$, and indeed $f$ being continuous, then $\exists c \in (-4, 0)$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

If I could prove $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on this interval, then $c$ would be unique and I would know the sign in this range.

In the same way, I would prove it's decreasing in $(-\infty, -4)$ and increasing in $(1, +\infty)$ (and since it has an asymptote at $y = -1$, there wouldn't be other roots).

Then by "exclusion", I would conclude it's positive in $(0, 1)$.

- Notice that I know all of this because I saw the plot (after having calculated the limits).

Yet to know the monotony of the function, I'd need $f'(x) > 0$ which is an even bigger mess.

Is there some theorem or condition that I could use to gain such information about its monotony?

Comment: By Descartes' rule of signs, the polynomial on the numerator has exactly one negative root which occurs in the interval $(-4,0)$. Let's call it $t$. This polynomial is positive in $(-4,t)$ and negative in $(t,0)$. Mean while, the denominator is throughout positive in $(-4,0)$ so sign of the numerator determines the sign of $f(x)$. Yes, the $c$ is unique and $c=t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of considering monotony, make use of the benefits of the numerator being a polynomial...

Let $p(x)=2x^3-x^2+5x+4\tag*{}$ and $q(x)=-2x^3-6x^2+8x.\tag*{}$

There is exactly one instance of sign change in the polynomial $p(-x)$. Thus, by [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), it must have *exactly one* negative root. Try to locate it.

$p(-\infty)\to -\infty$ and $p(-4)<0$ so this root cannot occur in $(-\infty,-4)$. It must occur somewhere in $(-4,0)$. It is also a root of $f(x)$ and in fact, it's the $c$ you are talking about.

Also note that there are no positive roots of $p(x)$ because $p(0)>0$ and $p'(x)>0$ for all $x$ so $p$ just continues to  increase.

Summary:

- $p(x)<0$ and $q(x)>0$ for all $x\in(-\infty,-4)$.
- $p(x)<0$ and $q(x)<0$ for all $x\in(-4,c)$.
- $p(x)=0$ at $x=c$.
- $p(x)>0$ and $q(x)<0$ for all $x\in(c,0)$.

$p(x)>0$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$ so the sign of $q(x)$ determines the sign of $f(x)$ in the remaining intervals.

$$\displaystyle \begin{array}{ c|c|c }
 & p( x) & q( x)\\
\hline
x\in ( -\infty ,-4) & - & +\\
\hline
x\in ( -4,\ c) & - & -\\
\hline
x=c & 0 & -\\
\hline
x\in ( c,0) & + & -\\
\hline
x\in ( 0,1) & + & +\\
\hline
x\in ( 1,\infty ) & + & -
\end{array}$$

Thus, $f$ is positive in $(-4,c)\cup(0,1)$, zero at $c$ and negative everywhere else on the domain $D$ you have suggested.
You can approximate $c$ using the bisection method...

$c\approx -0.62454$ (correct to five decimal places)

```
>>> f = lambda x: 2*x**3 -x**2 +5*x +4
>>> tolerance=5e-6
>>> a=-4
>>> b=0
>>> while abs(a-b) >= tolerance:
...     if f((c:=(a+b)/2))<0: a = c
...     else: b=c
...
>>> c
-0.6245460510253906
```

I hope that I have made everything clear and there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Really a great answer! Thank you!